# Argmin as intersection of sublevel sets

Tags: general-topology, optimization

Let $f:X\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$. I want to understand why $$\left\{x^*\in X:\; f(x^*)=\inf_Xf(x)\right\}=\bigcap_{\gamma>\inf_Xf}\left\{x\in X:\; f(x)\leq \gamma\right\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x^* \in X$ is such that $f(x^*) = \inf_X f(x)$, then trivially $f(x^*) < \gamma$ for each $\gamma > \inf_X f(x)$. Conversely, if $x^* \in X$ is such that $f(x^*) \neq \inf_X f(x)$, then $f(x^*) > \inf_X f(x)$, so for
$$
\gamma = \frac{f(x^*) + \inf_X f(x)}2 > \inf_X f(x)
$$
we have $f(x^*) > \gamma$, and thus $x^* \notin \{x \in X \mid f(x) \leq \gamma\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to prove this, which may add some understanding.

Let's calculate which elements are in both sides of the equation, starting with the right hand side which seems the most complex side.  (I'll use some notations I learned from Edsger W. Dijkstra; see [EWD1300](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html) for details.)$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$

---

For every $\;x^*\;$,

$$\calc
    \tag{RHS}
    x^* \in \bigcap_{\gamma > \inf_X f}\left\{x\in X:\; f(x)\leq \gamma\right\}
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;\bigcap\;$, set notation}
    \langle \forall \gamma : \gamma > \inf_X f : x^* \in X \land f(x^*)\leq \gamma \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{logic: extract part $\;x^* \in X\;$ not using $\;\gamma\;$ out of $\;\forall \gamma\;$ -- to simplify}
    x^* \in X \;\land\; \langle \forall \gamma : \gamma > \inf_X f : f(x^*)\leq \gamma \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{exchange domain and range in $\;\forall \gamma\;$ -- to introduce symmetry}
    x^* \in X \;\land\; \langle \forall \gamma : \gamma < f(x^*) : \gamma \leq \inf_X f \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{ordering: $\;<\;$ is a dense total order -- to simplify}
    x^* \in X \;\land\; f(x^*) \leq \inf_X f
\op\equiv\hint{by definition of $\;\inf\;$, for all $\;x \in X\;$, $\;f(x) \geq \inf_X f\;$}
    x^* \in X \;\land\; f(x^*) = \inf_X f
\op\equiv\hint{reintroduce set notation -- to reach the left hand side}
    x^* \in \left\{x^* \in X : f(x^*) = \inf_X f \right\}
    \tag{LHS}
\endcalc$$

By set extensionality, this completes the proof.

---

Note that apart from set theory and logic, this proof only uses a basic property of $\;\inf\;$ and the fact that $\;\lt\;$ is a dense total order on $\;\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}\;$: for such an order we have
$$
\langle \forall z : z \lt a : z \le b \rangle \;\equiv\; a \le b
$$
since (by splitting and then negating both sides using DeMorgan) this is equivalent to the combination of
\begin{align}
\tag{transitive}
& \langle \exists z : z \lt a : b \lt z \rangle \;\then\; b \lt a
\\
\tag{dense}
& b \lt a \;\then\; \langle \exists z : z \lt a : b \lt z \rangle
\end{align}
And the first answer by [Mees de Vries](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/75429/mees-de-vries) implicitly uses denseness where it uses$$
\frac{f(x^*) + \inf_X f}2
$$