# What is the definition of an "almost complete" order?

Tags: order-theory

In a recent answer to a question of mine (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2254369/11994) somebody mentions an "almost complete (partial) order" and an "almost complete dense order".

But I couldn't anywhere find a definition of this "almost complete" concept...

Comment: S is almost complete when for all not empty bounded above A, sup A in S.  It is also called LUB property and Dedekind complete.